# How to remove duplicates out of the UNION but ignore one column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

Consider the following table of data:

| FirstName | LastName | Department |
| --- | --- | --- |
| *Steve* | *Colton* | Accounting |
| Stacy | Beckham | Finance |
| Mary | Messi | Finance |
| *Steve* | *Colton* | Finance |
| Michael | Gretsky | Finance |

As you can see *Steve Colton* is in both Accounting and the Finance departments.
I want a query that should return Steve just once.

I can do the following which works but seems like more code than needed:

```
insert #FinalData(FirstName, LastName, Department)
select * from MyTable where Department = 'Accounting'

insert #FinalData(FirstName, LastName, Department)
select * from from MyTable mt1 where mt1.Department = 'Finance'
  and not exists (
      select 1 from #FinalData fd 
      where fd.FirstName = mt1.FirstName and fd.LastName = mt1.LastName
  )
```

I am looking for a more concise way to do this.  I tried UNION but there doesn't seem to be a way to exclude a column for purposes of deduplication.

Is there another way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `row_number()`.  If you want one row per first name (what your question implies), then:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by firstname order by department) as seqnum
      from MyTable 
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

This will choose "Accounting" over "Finance" for duplicates.